# How to use Cumulocity Device mgm / Configuration Repository?

Tags: cumulocity

I could upload a file on the "CONFIGURATION SNAPSHOTS REPOSITORY" page but I have not found any info on how to use this.

I would like to try to use this to deploy files to the device, if possible.

Which c8y_SupportedOperation (in java agent: supportedOperationType) I have to implement in order to be able to use this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the default devicemangement the supportedOperations are as follows:

c8y_DownloadConfigFile -> Downloading config files from Cumulocity to the device (operation contains link to the binary file).

c8y_UploadConfigFile -> Request for the device to upload current configuration as binary.

c8y_Configuration -> plain text configuration (stored in the device object and not as binary).

c8y_SoftwareList -> (Un-)Installing files from the software repository. The operation created always represents the complete list of software that should be present on the device.

Comment: great, thanks. I do see the full binary link in the operation this way. Now I "only" need to implement the download logic in the java agent... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have this configuration on the managedObject

```
{
 "c8y_SupportedOperations": [
   "c8y_Configuration"
  ]
}
```

You can send configuration to the device as a string, an operation with object 'c8y_Configuration' will be created. The config string is stored as a key on the c8y_Configuration object. You will see this UI. [image: basic text config UI]

---

If you have a managedObject with this configuration:

```
{
 "c8y_SupportedOperations": [
    "c8y_DownloadConfigFile"
  ]
}
```

Then you will get the configuration snapshot UI shown below.[image: snapshot UI] 
Sending a snapshot will create an operation with an 'c8y_DownloadConfigFile' object containing a key with the URL to the snapshot file.

---

If the managed object has this configuration:

```
{
 "c8y_SupportedOperations": [
    "c8y_UploadConfigFile"
  ]
}
```

You can create an operation with a 'c8y_UploadConfigFile' object. The device should then upload it's current config. The UI looks like this (note that there is no option to 'Save' the config or choose a snapshot).
[image: Get config UI]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do so from the `Configuration` tab in device view, in order to see the appropriate option the device needs to support the `c8y_DownloadConfigFile` operation.